# In Box2D Lite, I can't figure out what the "Box A faces" and "Box B faces" checks are for

Tags: box2d, collision-detection

I am studying the code of "[Box2D Lite](https://code.google.com/archive/p/box2d/downloads)" ([zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/box2d/Box2D_Lite.zip)), to understand in details how the implementation works. It is pretty obvious that the Collide function in collide.cpp implements the Separating Axis Theorem (SAT), but the checks performed right at the beginning uses smart math formulas to conclude (early) when there is no contact between the two boxes. The formulas imply transpose rotation matrixes, dot product, positions delta, without much of explanation or any clue.

```
// Box A faces
const Vec2 faceA = Abs(dA) - hA - absC * hB;
if (faceA.x > 0.0f || faceA.y > 0.0f)
    return 0;

// Box B faces
const Vec2 faceB = Abs(dB) - absCT * hA - hB;
if (faceB.x > 0.0f || faceB.y > 0.0f)
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "magic" formulas form the essence of the Separating Axis Theorem for rectangles.

Since Box2D Lite supports boxes only, only two axes per body need to be tested (cond. [1]). These axes are the body's *local* X and Y axes due to the rectangular shape (cond. [2]). The trivial method would be to project a body onto the world space normals of the faces of the other body, but both the above conditions allow us to simplify the body-axis projections by performing the projection relative to the body, and not the global origin, as follows:

```
faceA = Abs(dA) - hA - absC * hB
```

Let's go through what the above formula shows us.

`faceA` is the separation of the two bodies *relative* to A. `faceA.x` and `faceA.y` contain the separations on the normals of the lateral and longitudinal faces respectively. Note that all the calculations are done relative to A (see [2]).

`dA` is the position delta vector *relative* to A. We're taking the absolute value since we just want the distances between the closest faces of A and B on that axis.

`hA` contains the extents of A in the X and Y axes relative to A.

`hB` contains the extents of B in the X and Y axes relative to *B*. We have to transform this vector to A's space, which is why we transform `hB` by `absC`.

`absC` is equal to `abs(rotAT * rotB)`. As a rule, if there are two matrices `m1` and `m2` and a vector `v`, `(m1 * m2) * v` is equal to `m1 * (m2 * v)`, that is, transformation by multiplied matrices is done in the *reverse* order of their multiplication. Note that `m1 * m2` is **not** equal to `m2 * m1`. We take the absolute value again to remove all negative signs to retrieve the closest face.

This method will only work for right angled quadrilaterals (rectangles) because of [2].